# how can i extract the image url from <img src> tag under d<description > tag of xml file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing

XML Body:

```
<description>
<img src="http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/slideshow/02-2013/pics-serial-blasts/hyd-blasts-90.jpg" alt="In pics: Serial blasts in Hyderabad kill 14" title="In pics: Serial blasts in Hyderabad kill 14" border="0" width="90" height="62" align="left" hspace="5"/>At least 14 people are feared to have been killed in a series of explosions on Thursday evening which took place in Dilsukh Nagar bus stand area of Hyderabad.
</description>
```

Comment: What XML parser are you using?

Comment: we are using NSXMLParser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of `NSXMLParser` to parse XML. And then use below method to get attribute value from tag

`- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)nameSpaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`

You can extract attribute value like this.

```
if ([elementName isEqual:@"img"])
{
     NSLog(@"SRC: %@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"src"]);
}
```

And if you are not using any XML Parser and treating your XML as simple String then try to manipulate string like

```
NSString *imgURL= @"<description><img src=\"http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/slideshow/02-2013/pics-serial-blasts/hyd-blasts-90.jpg\" alt=\"In pics: Serial blasts in Hyderabad kill 14\" title=\"In pics: Serial blasts in Hyderabad kill 14\" border=\"0\" width=\"90\" height=\"62\" align=\"left\" hspace=\"5\"/>At least 14 people are feared to have been killed in a series of explosions on Thursday evening which took place in Dilsukh Nagar bus stand area of Hyderabad.</description>";

imgURL = [imgURL substringFromIndex:[imgURL rangeOfString:@"src="].location+[@"src=" length]+1];
imgURL = [imgURL substringToIndex:[imgURL rangeOfString:@"alt="].location-2];
NSLog(@"%@",imgURL);
```

Comment: we are using an NSXMLParser inputing an entire xml file..
in that case there are more than 50 description tag...